# How can I make iTerm use a dynamic working directory

Tags: zsh, iterm2

I'm having issue with iTerm's "working directory"

1. I can set it to a directory, but it only opens to that directory for new tabs and windows. Not for a new sessions (cold start of app)
2. I use multiple computers and share a config, my username is different on all three computers. Can I change the "working directory" to something like `/Users/$USER/development/` so it works on all 3 machines"?

Comment: `~/development/`

Comment: Try [cdpath](https://linux.101hacks.com/cd-command/cdpath/)